# Erro ao criar poup up menu em cardview

Tags: java, android, layout

Estou criando um aplicativo que utilizo de cardview na minha list. E estou com dificuldades de adicionar o menu no cardview, conforme imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha classe do cardview:

```
class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private List<Palheta> palhetas;

    public CustomAdapter(List<Palheta> palhetas) {
        this.palhetas = palhetas;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return palhetas.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return palhetas.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.card_view_palheta, null);
        TextView tv_nome = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_nome);
        simpleSwitch = (Switch) view.findViewById(R.id.simpleSwitch);
        ImageView imgCheck = view.findViewById(R.id.check);
        TextView textoCheck = view.findViewById(R.id.nomeCheck);
        if(palhetas.get(i).getSituacao().equals("COLETADA")){
           simpleSwitch.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
           simpleSwitch.setEnabled(false );
           imgCheck.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE );
           textoCheck.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imButton);
        try {
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getApplicationContext(), view);
                popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_palheta, popup.getMenu());
                popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Você clicou em : " + item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    }
                });
                popup.show();
            }
        });
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        tv_nome.setText(palhetas.get(i).getCodigo());
        TextView tv_endereco = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_endereco);
        tv_endereco.setText("Endereço: " + palhetas.get(i).getEndereco().getRua());
        TextView tv_bairro = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_bairro);
        tv_bairro.setText("Bairro: " + palhetas.get(i).getEndereco().getBairro());
        idPalheta = palhetas.get(i).getId();

        simpleSwitch.setTextOn("Sim"); // displayed text of the Switch whenever it is in checked or on state
        simpleSwitch.setTextOff("Não");
        simpleSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    alertDialog();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "NAO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                }
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

Erro que esta dando:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageButton
```

O que estou errando?

Comment: A view `imButton` deve ser do tipo `ImageView`, caso contrário você não conseguirá converter de um tipo para o outro. Ou você pode substituir `ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imButton);` por `AppCompatButton imageButton = (AppCompatButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imButton);`

Comment: Agora me retorna o erro: Process: com.diego.agentesendemias, PID: 12020
                  android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Failed to resolve attribute at index 6: TypedValue{t=0x1c/d=0xff009688 a=1 r=0x10600d3}
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:543)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essa exceção é lançada quando o tipo que você declarou na classe é diferente da view que usou no layout.

`ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imButton);`

Nessa linha você está tentando colocar a view `imButton` do tipo `AppCompatButton` em um tipo `ImageButton`.

O ideal nesse caso é usar `AppCompatImageButton`, tanto no layout, quanto na classe Java.